# InputStream on socket reads zeros

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, inputstream

I try receive a raw binary packet on my server side. I have control over the data format and specified the first 4 bytes of a packet to describe the length of the packet (it is an int value converted to byte[] and back). This works very well, I get the correct numbers (I can also monitor and check the client side). Here is the code:

```
is = connectionSocket.getInputStream();
byte[] intArray = new byte[4];
//read the 4-byte int value to array
is.read(intArray, 0, 4);
int packetLength = ByteBuffer.wrap(intArray).getInt();
```

I then want to read the package (excluding the length-header) to a custom-fit byte array:

```
byte[] packet = new byte[packetLength];//make a buffer ready
is.read(packet, 0, packetLength);//read the whole packet to array
```

If the sent byte[] has a length of 1444 or less, everything works fine. But packets beyond this limit won't be received properly. The packet-array will be filled correctly with data at the beginning, but after the limit, there are only zeros until the end like this

```
Positon: ...|1440|1441|1442|1443|1444|1445|1446|1447|.........|packetLength-1
Data:    ...| 59 |-73 | 125| -3 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |..zeros..| 0
```

From my days as a 13-years-old-wannabe-internet-tuning-master I can still remember, that there is a standard MTU (maximum transmission unit) of about 1500 bytes on Windows machines. Indeed my receiving network adapter has an MTU of 1500. That's suspiciously close to 1444, so I increased the MTU, but sadly with no results. Java should not bother me with such low-level stuff, but maybe this isn't a coincidence. btw, the client is an Android smartphone, receiver a Windows 7 machine.

Does anybody have another idea or even better a solution?

Comment: You have to get the size of the packet as: int size = is.read(packet, 0, packetLength);

Comment: Wow, many thanks!!! Why the hell is this necessary? just adding "int size =" resulted in a correctly filled packet-array, even if don't use "size" anymore. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: This is not a bug, it's how it was implements (for performance reasons). See, resizing an array it's too costly. By using a fixed sized buffers + packet size return you can improve performance by analysing the fixed length buffer with high speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring the count returned by `read(),` and assuming that it filled the buffer. It isn't obliged to do that. See the Javadoc.

The simple way to do what you're doing, correctly, is to use `DataInputStream.readInt(),` followed by `readFully().`

NB Contrary to your comment, merely adding `int size =` didn't have that effect at all, of course. It isn't possible. What changed was the timing, for some other reason, so that four bytes really arrived.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found out about the race-condition-like nature of read myself, but thanks for the help and clarification. I noticed it when I observed that setting debug stops solved the problem, that gave the buffers time to do their job. Using DataInputStream is also much nicer to code, thanks again. Here is my (hopefully) final solution:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
int packetLength = dis.readInt();
byte[] packet = new byte[packetLength];//make a buffer ready       
dis.readFully(packet);//read full packet to buffer
```

Comment: There is no 'race-condition-like nature of read'. There is simply a return value that you must not ignore, and a contract that says it will block until at least one byte of data is available, no more.